# How do I objectively measure my mouse precision?

Tags: mouse

I have the *feeling* that my mouse "jumps" every now and then ever so slightly (maybe a pixel or two) into the wrong direction when I use it on my mouse pad as opposed to using it on my desk.

Now, before I replace my mouse pad (or throw it away and just buy a stand-alone wrist support), I'd like to **objectively measure the difference**---maybe I'm just getting old and shaky and my subconscious tries to blame it on the pad (or the mouse).

Is there some "standard" way to do that? Maybe some game where I have to trace some symbol and the system records how far off I was? When I google for "mouse accuracy test", I get those "shoot-'em-up" style of games, which is not the type of accuracy I want to measure.

Comment: How would the computer tell apart incorrect jumps from intentional shakes?

Comment: see https://techscsi.com/mouse-dpi-test/

Comment: @gronostaj: It doesn't need to. I'd do some tests with (a) my usual mouse and mousepad, (b) my usual mouse without mousepad, (c) another mouse with mousepad and (d) another mouse without mousepad. If all results are the same (within a margin of statistical significance), I'm shaky, otherwise, I have identified the culprit.

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks, I'll try that.